The Python code for calculating the RSI of a coin is being converted to JavaScript, but the values are different. What could be the reason?
This is python code
PYTHON
import pandas as pd

def get_rsi(ohlcv, period, st):
    ohlcv["close"] = ohlcv["close"]
    delta = ohlcv["close"].diff()
    up, down = delta.copy(), delta.copy()
    up[up < 0] = 0
    down[down > 0] = 0
    _gain = up.ewm(com=(period - 1), min_periods=period).mean()
    _loss = down.abs().ewm(com=(period - 1), min_periods=period).mean()
    RS = _gain / _loss
    return float(pd.Series(100 - (100 / (1 + RS)), name="RSI").iloc[st])

JAVASCRIPT
export function getRSI(ohlcv, period) {
  if (ohlcv.length < period + 1) {
    throw new Error("Data length must be greater than period");
  }

  let gains = [];
  let losses = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < ohlcv.length; i++) {
    let diff = ohlcv[i].close - ohlcv[i - 1].close;
    if (diff > 0) {
      gains.push(diff);
      losses.push(0);
    } else if (diff < 0) {
      gains.push(0);
      losses.push(Math.abs(diff));
    } else {
      gains.push(0);
      losses.push(0);
    }
  }

  let avgGain = gains.slice(0, period).reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0) / period;
  let avgLoss = losses.slice(0, period).reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0) / period;

  let RS = avgGain / avgLoss;
  let RSI = 100 - 100 / (1 + RS);
  return RSI;
}

do you know the reason..?
I tried to test it
But RSI results were different
there is no Pandas for Javascript.
The JavaScript code generated through ChatGPT isn't effective. Could you please help me understand the reason behind it?

If ChatGPT wrotre that code, ask ChatGPT. [ask]

I asked it , he doesn't know about it :(

I think that's Julien's point. ChatGPT doesn't know anything.

  let avgGain = gains.slice(0, period).reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0) / period;
  let avgLoss = losses.slice(0, period).reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0) / period;

in JS is basically equivalent to
    _gain = up[:period].mean()
    _loss = down[:period].abs().mean()

in Python,
instead of
    _gain = up.ewm(com=(period - 1), min_periods=period).mean()
    _loss = down.abs().ewm(com=(period - 1), min_periods=period).mean()

.
The difference shall be clear.
